# Does the blow-up induce an isomorphism in top cohomology (real coefficients)?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, blowup

Let $X$ be a (possibly singular) compact complex manifold of complex dimension $n$ and let $Y\subset X$ be a submanifold along we blow-up $X$. So we get a blow-down map $P:Bl_Y X\to X$.

> Is $P^*: H^{2n}(X,\mathbb R)\to H^{2n}(Bl_YX,\mathbb R)$ an
>   isomorphism?

---

So far I looked at the Mayer Vietoris sequence for $Bl_YX = (Bl_YX\setminus E) \cup E$, where $E$ is the exceptional divisor. We also call the corresponding intersection $Z$.  If $X$ is non-singular, then $Z=S^{2n-1}$.

$Bl_YX\setminus E \simeq  X\setminus Y$ and as $\dim Y \le 2n-2$, it follows that $H^{2n}(X) = H^{2n}(X\setminus Y)$ and $H^{2n-1}(X) = H^{2n-1}(X\setminus Y)$. Also, $\dim E = 2n-2$, so $H^{2n}(E)=H^{2n-1}(E) =0$.

Thus
$$\to H^3(X) \stackrel j \to H^3 (Z)\to H^4(Bl_YX)\stackrel {i^*}\to H^4(X) \to 0$$
is exact.

Thus in order for $H^4(Bl_YX)$ to be isomorphic to $H^4(X)$, we need $j$ to be surjective.

But even so, this would only tell me that $i^*$ is an isomorphism. I am interested in $P^*$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the situation where $Y\subset X$ are both complex manifolds, this is true. As both $X$ and $Bl_YX$ are complex manifolds and all complex manifolds are orientable, both have top cohomology $\Bbb R$. So it suffices to show that $P^*$ is either injective or surjective on top cohomology in order to prove it is an isomorphism. We first note that $P_*: H_*(Bl_YX)\to H_*(X)$ is surjective, as $P$ is an isomorphism away from $Y$ and $Y$ is small. By duality, this gives us the injectivity required on the top piece of cohomology, and so $P^*$ is surjective and thus an isomorphism.

Comment: Dear KReiser, could you detail more why $Y$ is small implies that $P_*$ is surjective ?

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Clearly the fundamental class is mapped to the fundamental class by this map. For any homology class on $X$ of lower dimension, locally one may move it away from $Y$ by a boundary (locally one can choose $\Bbb R$ coordinates on $X$ as a smooth manifold so that $Y$ is a real codimension $\geq 2$ linear space) and you can see that such a class is the image of some homology class in $Bl_YX$.

Comment: For what it's worth, there's also the general fact that for any map of orientable manifolds which takes the fundamental class to the fundamental class, we have a surjection on homology. I think I first learned about this from an exercise in Hatcher, but it's been a few years.

Comment: Dear KReiser, thank you very much for the precision.